# Implementing exit app button in the persistent notification

Tags: java, android, service, android-service, android-notifications

My app runs a background service indicated by the persistent notification. Users need to use the toggle button in MainActivity to turn on/off this service and thus to remove the persistent notification.

Now I want to implement a `notification action` that can turn this service off & as well as the toggle within MainActivity. All in all, it should be `an exit button` to close my app and background service directly from the notification.

How do I achieve this?

> note that I have two different java files, one for NotificationService
> and the other is MainActivity. The toggle belongs to MainActivity.

> edit: Is this okay to call System.exit(0) if I use pending intent with
> BroadCastReceiver to exit from the app completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use PendingIntent with BroadcastReceiver or Service to perform this. Here is an example of PendingIntent with BroadcastReciever.

**Build a Notification**

```
        public static void createNotif(Context context){

        Intent intentAction = new Intent(context,StopServerBroadcast.class);

        //This is optional if you have more than one buttons and want to differentiate between two
        intentAction.putExtra("action","actionName");

        pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,1,intentAction,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        drivingNotifBldr = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_NAME)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.steeringwheel)
                .setContentTitle("Stop Service")
                .setContentText("Example Text")
                .addAction(R.drawable.smallmanwalking, "On/off", pIntent)
                .setOngoing(true);
        ...

    }
```

**Now the receiver which will receive this Intent**

```
        public class StopServerBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            //Toast.makeText(context,"recieved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            String action=intent.getStringExtra("action");
            if(action.equals("action1")){
                performAction1();
                /*
                
                    Code that will stop your service
                    
                */
            }
          
        }

    }
```

**Register Receiver in Manifest**

```
<receiver
    android:name=".StopServerBroadcast"
    android:enabled="true" />
```

Comment: Okay, this seems promising. But I still have one problem, since the on/off toggle is in MainActivity, if I create this new class with BroadcastReceiver then How am I gonna access that toggle from this class?

Comment: Is this okay to call System.exit(0) or this goes against the play store policy?

Comment: Make one static boolean variable isActive = true or false and in background service continue check its true or false if its off by brodcast reciever then stop server with validation of that variable

Comment: This is genius! Thank you brother, you saved my day.